# Change normal regression model to rolling regression

Tags: r, regression

I have a sample data set with number of sales for 1000 different products in 13 countries over 3 years:

13 Countries = (US, China, UK…)
1000 Products = (Prod A, B, C …)

Number of Sales --> my dependent variable.

Number of Clicks and 3 more variables as independent variable.

I've coded a regression model and it works. In the next step I would like to do a rolling regression: How do I have to adapt the code for that?

Thanks for your help and many greetings! :)

```
# prepare data
nest_dt = raw_data %>%
    group_by(product, country) %>%
    nest()

# function
lm_function = function(data, formula) {
    lm(formula = formula,
       data = data)
}

# regression
lm_data = nest_data %>%
    mutate(lm = map(
        .x = data,
        .f = lm_function,
        formula = sales ~ clicks + needs + guesses + interests
    ))

# show solution
solution_data = lm_data %>%
    mutate(solution = map(lm, sw_tidy)) %>%
    unnest(solution) %>%
    select(-data, -lm)

# where to put?!?
rollapply(lm_function, width=10, roll)
```

Comment: can you please attacha a sample of your data using `?dput`

Comment: @OttoKässi Thank your for your reply, I'm trying to attach a sample of my data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `roll_lm` function from the `roll` package. See the description here: [Package ‘roll’ on Cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roll/roll.pdf)